# 自作ライブラリがインストールされている状態(pip install)で、ローカルのファイルを参照してpytestを実行する方法

Tags: python, テスト

## 環境

- python 3.6.6
- pytest 4.0.0

## 背景

Pythonの自作ライブラリをpytestでテストしたいです。
自作ライブラリはpip installできるようになっています。
`pip install git+https://github.com/sample/sampleapi`

#### フォルダ構成

```
project/
│  pytest.ini
│  setup.py
│  
├─sampleapi/
│  │  api.py
│  │  
│          
│      
└─tests/
    │  test.py
    │
```

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='sampleapi',
...)
```

## 問題

私の環境では自作ライブラリがインストールされています。
この状態で`pytest tests`を実行すると、`pip install`した方のsampleapiが参照されます。
したがって、テストの実行結果を元にsampleapiを修正した場合、再度pip installする必要があります。

自作ライブラリがインストールされている状態で、ローカルのファイルを参照してpytestを実行するには、どうしたらよいでしょうか？
自作ライブラリがインストールされていなければ、ローカルのファイルが参照されました。

Comment: 思わず書いてしまったのかもしれませんが、こんな記事があるので、ファイル名/モジュール名にはご注意を。[Pythonでtest.pyを作るな！](https://qiita.com/msmhrt/items/7e2a335a4c64bcc6e044), ["random.py", "test.py"などのファイル名を付けるとハマる](https://minus9d.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/11/16/161805)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2つの方法があります。

1. `PYTHONPATH` を設定する
2. `tox` を使ってテスト環境を分離する

1は、以下のようにコマンドラインで実行します。

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. pytest tests
```

このように毎回書きたくない場合のために、 https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pythonpath/ というプラグインが提供されているので、これを使うのもよいでしょう。

2は、 https://pypi.org/project/tox/ を使うことでテスト環境をvirtualenv内に分離する方法です。virtualenvやvenvを手動でテスト用に作成するのでもよいですが、toxを使うのが一般的です。